# $(window).on('scroll'); is not working after setting it off

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, progress-bar

I am doing JS animation inside if and I don't want to have it repeated after it reaches to its place so I used `$(window).off('scroll');` now every element after that `#container` cannot use scroll event and I tried to turn the scroll on but it is not working `$(window).on('scroll');.`
Any idea?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#container').offset().top,
       hH = $('#container').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT-wH) , wS);
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
   // some code
   $(window).off('scroll');


   }

});
```

Comment: well you are saying turn off all the events... so if you want to only do certain ones you need to turn off just than instance. Look into namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your off call unbinds all events, not just one. You need to unbind that one instance. It is either done with function reference

```
var myScroll1 = function () {
  $(window).off("scroll", myScroll1)
}
$(window).on("scroll", myScroll1)
```

or namespaces

```
$(window).on("scroll.scroll1", function () {
  $(window).off("scroll.scroll1", myScroll1)
})
```